# Private encfs mount (limited access per-process)

Tags: encfs

How to restrict access to an encfs mount to (a) specific process(es)?

By default, encfs is visible only to the current user (except when using the `--public` option).

Running encfs as another user has the drawback of being prone to permission issues, as the files will be owned by the other user, possibly with restrictive permissions. I don't want to deal with permission issues.

So I want to run encfs by the same user, and per-process access restriction being handled by e.g. control groups (cgroups) or namespaces.

Comment: Do you really want to hide your files from *yourself*? You don't even trust your own programs? Maybe your security model needs a more secure setup (computer, OS, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions below use namespaces through the [`unshare`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unshare) command. Processes in other namespaces will not see the mount.

We can't use `unshare -r` because it's run with `nogroups` group rights, that encfs/fuse don't like.

## Solution 1 (will ask for root rights at every launch)

We're using `sudo unshare` to create the bind mount and mark it as private. Once done, we change the user to sudo caller (`sudo -u "#$SUDO_UID" -g "#$SUDO_GID"`) end explicitely remove root rights (`sudo -K`). At that point, we can call `encfs` and start to do stuff with `your_program_here`. When terminated, the private bind mount is deleted by the parent root bash (so without asking again for the user root password) so it is no more visible by root through `mount -l`.

```
enc_dir="/path/to/enc_dir"
mount_point="/path/to/plain_dir"
RUN_CMD="mount --bind \"$mount_point\" \"$mount_point\"; \
         mount --make-private \"$mount_point\"; \
         sudo -u \"#\$SUDO_UID\" -g \"#\$SUDO_GID\" \
             bash -c \"sudo -K; \
                       encfs \\\"$enc_dir\\\" \\\"$mount_point\\\"; \
                       your_program_here \\\"\\\$@\\\"; \
                       fusermount -u -z \\\"$mount_point\\\" \
                     \" - \"\$@\"; \
        umount \"$mount_point\""
sudo unshare -m bash -c "$RUN_CMD" - "optional" "arguments"
```

`your_program_here` can be whatever you want, e.g. `bash` for a command prompt. You can pass arguments to this program ($1="optional" $2="arguments") properly.

*Source: [Launch a sudoed command upon script termination?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268059/launch-a-sudoed-command-upon-script-termination) answer by Celada + see sources solution 2.*

## Solution 2 (has critical vulnerability if using unshare >= v2.27.1)

To avoid `unshare` being run as root, we need to use the setuid bit on it.

```
sudo groupadd unshare
sudo adduser $USER unshare
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/unshare
sudo chown root:unshare /usr/bin/unshare
```

**Warning**: This provokes a vulnerability in recent unshare versions (since [v2.27.1](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/bc7f9b95c04a8a6bb60cf2e58df47567f30cb989)) and must not be used, as unshare no longer drops root rights when executing the command, so anyone could have root access. A workaround exist and is described [here](http://benjam.info/blog/posts/2015-09-05-unshare-updates/).

Then (possibly a new terminal is required):

```
unshare -m
```

We should now have a shell with `$` user sign, not `#` root sign. Now, we need to explicitly specify `private` or `rprivate` in the mount options (explaination in sources below) and then launch encfs.

```
enc_dir="/path/to/enc_dir"
mount_point="/path/to/plain_dir"
sudo mount --bind "$mount_point" "$mount_point"
sudo mount --make-private "$mount_point"
encfs "$enc_dir" "$mount_point"
```

Processes started from this shell will be able to view the mount point. Other processes won't.

*Source: [Hiding an encrypted folder in a shared system without root access (unshare -m)](http://www.lgqyc.com/hiding-an-encrypted-folder-in-a-shared-system-without-root-access-unshare-m/) commented by Philipp Wendler & [Cant' get per process mount namespaces to work](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1540271#p1540271) answer by ub1quit33*

## Solution 3 ? (best of breed)

Avenues to be further explored: There's probably something to do by putting Solution 1 script in a `.sh` file, and setting `setuid` bit + chown on it like in Solution 2. `#$SUDO_*ID` variables may need to be replaced by something else and `sudo -K` effectiveness needs to be tested.

Also, enc_dir and mount_point variables should not be parameterizable as they are not used safely. Otherwise, they should be escaped, or better, they should be passed as unshare first parameters (hence $@ should be replaced by the range of positional parameters ${@:2}).

Or fill a feature request for encfs/fuse support in `unshare -r` to unshare developers...

Comment: Thanks for this post!

Is the unshare vulnerability to be fixed anytime soon? Is this already reported as a bug?

Also, what I dislike in this solution is that to make the mount point private I have to use root privileges. I haven't found another solution so far, but: Why is that? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @olenz: I've put some ideas in solution 3 if root rights is not an option for you at every launch. `unshare` vulnerability "is not a bug, it's a feature" since the `setuid` technique has been replaced by `unshare -r`. But encfs/fuse can't run in `unshare -r`.